# How do I make a UCI connect to my C++ GUI?

Tags: c++, pipe, chess

I'm trying to connect the Stockfish 14 UCI to my C++ program that takes the data from the UCI and properly displays it onto a chess board using SDL2. I've had major troubles with this. I've tried the _popen function but that function doesn't allow me to input multiple commands. I've also tried the Windows API but there's hardly any good tutorials out there that properly explain the 'CreatePipe' function. QProcess is another alternative I've heard but I could not find any download to the library. How do I create a pipe between two processes? I'm at a loss of direction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to input multiple commands?